# Why does python decide to reuse the same object

Tags: python, garbage-collection

When I instantiate an object in a loop without assigning it to any variable, I thought it would create new object for each iteration. But the code below seems to indicate we reuse the same object.

Can someone explain why this is happening? Smart GC logic or interpreter optimization?

```
for x in range(10):
  print(id(TestClass()))

# output
140640390008776
140640390008776
140640390008776
140640390008776
140640390008776
140640390008776
140640390008776
140640390008776
140640390008776
140640390008776
```

Comment: Have a look at the bytecode.

Comment: That's not a question about Python itself. Python is just the language definition. It's a question concerning a specific implementation of Python.

Comment: It *is* creating a new object. The `id` is only guaranteed to be unique *for the lifetime* of a object.